# how to add line break in a text read by BufferReader in attempt to convert it to pdf with iText7

Tags: java, itext7

Here is the text file I create

```
     try {
    File info = new File("StudentInfo.txt");
    
    if(!info.exists()) {
        info.createNewFile();
    }
    
    PrintWriter D = new PrintWriter(info);
    
    D.println("Student Name "+" : "+"MUSTAPHA HASSAN;\n"+"Class \t\t"+"\t\t: "+"PRIM 
              6A;\n"+"No.in Class \t "+" : "+"43;\n"+"Position\t\t\t: "+"2nd;");                
    D.close();
    
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

I got this output for the text File

```
   Student Name  : MUSTAPHA HASSAN;
   Class                : PRIM 6A;
   No.in Class    : 43;
   Position         : 2nd;
```

Converting Text File to pdf

```
  try {
    String Z = "C:\\Users\\TEXT.pdf";
    OutputStream D = new FileOutputStream(Z);
    PdfWriter PW = new PdfWriter(D);
    PdfDocument Test = new PdfDocument(PW);
    Document document = new Document(Test, PageSize.A4);
  
      Paragraph T = new Paragraph();
      
       
     public static void PARA (Paragraph T , String line) {
         StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
         while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
             T.add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()));
         }
     }

      BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\StudentInfo.txt"));
        String line = bf.readLine();
        PARA(T , line);
         while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
             PARA(T , line);
         
         }
         bf.close();

     document.add(T);
     document.close();
  }catch (Exception e) {

  }
```

the pdf  output is this

```
 Student Name : MUSTAPHA HASSANClass : PRIM 6ANo.in Class : 43Position : 2nd
```

is there any way that the pdf output will Looks the same as that in the text ?

I want the pdf output in this form

```
   Student Name  : MUSTAPHA HASSAN;
   Class                : PRIM 6A;
   No.in Class    : 43;
   Position         : 2nd;
```

Guide me please.

Comment: Try `PARA(T , line + '\r');`

Comment: it does'nt work still the output is                                                                                     `Student Name : MUSTAPHA HASSANClass : PRIM 6ANo.in Class : 43Position : 2nd`

Comment: Ok, well, I just thought that was worth a shot.  I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: thank you appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void PARA (Paragraph T , String line) {
     StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
     while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        //Remove T.add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()));

     //Replace it with
     T.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
    
     }

 }
```

then as Steve say's "Try PARA(T , line + '\r');"

finally you have this as output

```
         Student Name : MUSTAPHA HASSAN
         Class        : PRIM 6A
         No.in Class  : 43
         Position     : 2nd
```